# UITableViewCell updating multiple image alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a simple UITableViewController. I added a cell.imageView.image for all cells but I hide the image using alpha for some cells. When I scroll down, other cells begin hiding the image. I have tried to resolve the issue by focusing on just one cell, but the same problem persists where random cells begin hiding the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"];
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 0;
    }            
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: first, use the property hidden(boolean) instead of alpha if you want to hide something

Comment: cell.imageView.alpha = !(indexPath.row == 2);

Comment: you are used wrong approach Apple iOS provide hide and show property then why you used this type of setting alpha. as @Masterfego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is correct. But here is another suggestion. Instead of setting the `alpha` you can change `imageview's` hidden property as well like :

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;
} else {
    cell.imageView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Also, it will be better if you will make a custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the code to:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.imageView.alpha = 0;
} else {
    cell.imageView.alpha = 1;
}
```

The problem here is that the cells are reused and if you display a cell at row 2, then that cell moves off-screen and is reused for some cell at path 10, that cell will still have the alpha set to 0.

Therefore you have to tell the cell to have an alpha of 1 *unless* it is at indexPath 2.

You might want to consider using the [`hidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property instead of setting the `alpha` to 1 and 0.

That might be more correct for various reasons if you compare the explanation of the properties in the docs:

> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view with subviews has the effect of hiding those subviews and any view descendants they might have. This effect is implicit and does not alter the hidden state of the receiver’s descendants.
>
> Hiding the view that is the window’s current first responder causes the view’s next valid key view to become the new first responder.
>
> The value of this property reflects the state of the receiver only and does not account for the state of the receiver’s ancestors in the view hierarchy. Thus this property can be NO but the receiver may still be hidden if an ancestor is hidden.

vs.

> The value of this property is a floating-point number in the range 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0 represents totally transparent and 1.0 represents totally opaque. This value affects only the current view and does not affect any of its embedded subviews.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote this answer but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"#2 is HERE";
} else {
    cell.imageView.hidden = NO;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", indexPath.row];
}
```

Use property hidden(Boolean) when you want to hide something

Answer (score 0):

All of this answers are correct.. just to simplify..

```
cell.imageView.alpha = !(indexPath.row == 2);

or 

cell.imageView.hidden = (indexPath.row == 2);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the alpha you can change imageview's hidden property as well like :

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;
} else {
    cell.imageView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Or you can use the custom cell which is much better.